# Regex.Unescape : ArgumentException

Tags: c#, regex, escaping, argumentexception

I've been struggling with this problem for quite sometime now and googling couldn't provide much help. I have strings which contain both "**valid**" and "**invalid**" escape sequences like so,

```
str1 = "love\u007c\u000B\n";  // Valid escape sequences
str2 = "title=\x22\t\n";     // Invalid escape sequences. Insufficient hexadecimal digits
str3 = "\love\007c\u000B\n"; // Invalid escape sequences. Unrecognized escape sequences.
```

When I use the method `Regex.Unescape(str1);`, I get the result that I'm looking for, which is `"love|"`.
With `Regex.Unescape(str2);`, I get an `ArgumentException: Insufficient hexadecimal digits` but what I'm actually looking for is `title=\x22`.
And with `Regex.Unescape(str3);`, I get an `ArgumentException: Unrecognized escape sequence \l`but what I'm actually looking for is `\love|`.

My question is, how can I handle such strings which contain both valid and invalid escape sequences, such that any invalid escape sequence gets ignored while the valid sequences get replaced with their appropriate character literals. Any code snippets or links would be extremely helpful.

Comment: if you want \ after `Unescape` then you need escape it in string, for example `str3= "\\\\love\u007c\u000B\n"`, or `str3= @"\\love\u007c\u000B\n"`

Comment: I am curious _why_ invalid strings are being passed in. I'm guessing they are user-entered and not coming directly from `Regex.Escape()` somewhere? (I'm wondering if it's feasible to prevent these strings from being invalid in the first place.)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @Grundy I do need the \ after `Unescape()`. However, I have no way of identifying whether the \ is part of an invalid escape sequence.  
  
@Wiseguy You  guessed it right. These are user generated strings, extracted from snippets of html and hence can be anything.

Comment: @maverick can you provide how you get this string?

Answer (score 0):

In `C#` there `regular string` literals and `verbatim string` literals. I'm guessing by your experience regular string literals are not the intended representation. Using the `@` symbol before the quoted string gives you the verbatim literal type:

```
string str1 = @"love\u007c\u000B\n";
string str2 = @"title=\x22\t\n";
string str3 = @"\love\007c\u000B\n";
```

Have a look at the brief [String Literals explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) on MSDN — it should shed some light into the distinct differences of literals and how/where to use each flavor.